# JSF outputtext value not showing in pdf using itext

Tags: jsf, itext

Im trying to export an xhtml to pdf using itext and im passing values from first page to the second page and im trying to print the second page my problem is the outputtext values passed from the first page are shown in the second page but when i generate the pdf the static text is there but the values i inserted are not there 
this is the first pages inputtext

```
<h:inputText id="username" value="#{PrintController.name}" ></h:inputText>
```

and this is the second page

```
<h:outputText value="#{PrintController.name}" />
```

this is the command button im using

```
    <h:commandButton value="Create PDF" action="#{PrintController.create}">
    <f:param name="action" value="http://localhost:8080/test/more.xhtml" />
    </h:commandButton>
```

this is the print methode

```
try {
        final ITextRenderer iTextRenderer = new ITextRenderer();

        iTextRenderer.setDocument(url);
        iTextRenderer.layout();
        File file=new File("C:/files/invoice.pdf");

        final FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = 
                    new FileOutputStream(file);


        iTextRenderer.createPDF(fileOutputStream);
        fileOutputStream.close();
        Faces.sendFile(file, true);
    } catch (final DocumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

the generated pdf does not show the value of the outputText but its shown in the second page which im changing to pdf

Comment: url is the value passed in the commandButton which is the url of the page i want to export to pdf.
sorry im still learning JSF 
can you explain more what do you mean with different session ? thank you

Comment: now i get it i was not aware about the sessions and requests and im using @SessionScoped
yes sir now i understand the problem